# Why does VaadinRouter route me when not authenticated?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vaadin-router

I am fiddling around with VaadinRouter,trying to protect routes.
Below you can see the onBeforeEnter code of my component to protect:

```js
    authenticatedDummy = true;

    public onBeforeEnter(
        location: RouterLocation,
        commands: PreventAndRedirectCommands
      ): Promise<unknown> | RedirectResult | undefined {
        if (this.authenticatedDummy) {
          console.log('OnBeforeEnter');
    
          return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve(commands.redirect('/home'));
            }, 2000);
          });
        }
        return undefined;
      }
```

I do not understand why the router routes me, if `authenticatedDummy` is false.
As I read the code, `if authenticatedDummy is true, redirect me to '/home'` .

Is this the correct way of reading it or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have build the script wrong.
It should have been:

```js
 public onBeforeEnter(
        location: RouterLocation,
        commands: PreventAndRedirectCommands
      ): Promise<unknown> | RedirectResult | undefined {
        if (!this.isAuthorized()) {
          console.log('Guarded!');
    
          return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve(commands.redirect('/'));
            }, 2000);
          });
        }
        return undefined;
      }
```

It is working like this!